# Correlation between binary variables in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, correlation, confusion-matrix

I am trying to calculate the correlation between binary variables using Cramer's statistics:

```
def cramers_corrected_stat(confusion_matrix):

    chi2 = ss.chi2_contingency(confusion_matrix)[0]
    n = confusion_matrix.sum()
    phi2 = chi2/n
    r,k = confusion_matrix.shape
    phi2corr = max(0, phi2 - ((k-1)*(r-1))/(n-1))    
    rcorr = r - ((r-1)**2)/(n-1)
    kcorr = k - ((k-1)**2)/(n-1)
    return np.sqrt(phi2corr / min( (kcorr-1), (rcorr-1)))
```

However I do not know how to apply the code above within my dataset:

```
    CL  UP  NS  P   CL_S
480  1  0   1   0   1
1232 1  0   1   0   1
2308 1  1   1   0   1
1590 1  0   1   0   1
497  1  1   0   0   1
... ... ... ... ... ...
1066    1   1   1   0   1
1817    1   0   1   0   1
2411    1   1   1   0   1
2149    1   0   1   0   1
1780    1   0   1   0   1
```

I would appreciate your help in guiding me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you made is not proper for your dataset.

So, use the follow function `cramers_V(var1,var2)` given as follows.

```
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency
def cramers_V(var1,var2):
  crosstab =np.array(pd.crosstab(var1,var2, rownames=None, colnames=None)) # Cross table building
  stat = chi2_contingency(crosstab)[0] # Keeping of the test statistic of the Chi2 test
  obs = np.sum(crosstab) # Number of observations
  mini = min(crosstab.shape)-1 # Take the minimum value between the columns and the rows of the cross table
  return (stat/(obs*mini))
```

example code using the function is as fllows.

```
cramers_V(df["CL"], df["NS"])
```

If you want to calculate all possible pairs of your dataset, use this code.

```
import itertools
for col1, col2 in itertools.combinations(df.columns, 2):
    print(col1, col2, cramers_V(df[col1], df[col2]))
```

Comment: thank you so much Gilseung Ahn. I tried the itertools as you suggested but I got an error on the column name. It is weird as I selected in my dataframe only binary variables

Comment: Show your error message. I would help you to solve it.

Comment: thanks. It is a keyError that shows the name of the column (for example CL). -> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)

Comment: Hmm.. It is weird. You mean "print(col1, col2, cramers_V(df[col1], df[col2]))" makes a error?

Comment: I got it. Try to change df[col1] and df[col2] to df.loc[:, col1] and df.loc[:, col2], respectively.

Comment: I changed it as follows:     `print(col1, col2, cramers_V(df.loc[:, col1] and df.loc[:, col2]))` but there is still the same error

Comment: can the above be used for two binary variables?